# How to return two data frames from a function that iterates over two columns of a third data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, zip

I am trying to return two data frames out of a function that I am iterating over two columns of another data frame but I get a value error message. Ex:

```
data={'source':['a','b','c','d'], 'target':['e','f','g','h']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)

def func (source,target,sources, targets):
    sources=sources.append(source)
    target=targets.append(target)
    return sources, targets 

sources=pd.DataFrame()
targets=pd.DataFrame()
sources,targets=[func(i,j,sources,targets) for i,j in zip(df['source'],df['target'])]
```

When I run this code I get this error:

`valueerror: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT** I know this specifically can be done much easier without iterating but I need to do it this way because in the actual code I have to get some information regarding each source and target from a database and then append that information to the sources data frame

Comment: My apologies, I can’t get my head around this logic.  Please state the exact issue clearly; as this appears to be an XY problem.  Are you trying to combine column data ... ?  Generally, if you (we) find yourself iterating a DataFrame, there is very likely a better solution.

Comment: This is an oversimplification of what my code does because the actual code is fairly long. Df has a list of sources and targets and for each combination of source and target I have to get info from a database, construct two data frames and then append those data frames to already existing data frames for the previous source and target. The problem is when returning two data frames, if I want to return one the code runs correctly

Comment: Are you just trying to split the two column into separate dataframes? If so you can do that like this ```sources = df.loc[:, ["source"]]```. You can repeat for target

Comment: The Error you got is because of assigning a list containing more values (>2)  to two variables in the line `sources,targets=[func(i,j,sources,targets) for i,j in zip(df['source'],df['target'])]`. Simply, `a,b = [1,2]` will work but not `a,b = [(1,2)]`.  You may just try to print the output alone and check whether you are getting the expected result. If not, please paste the error as well as the expected output for the sample dataframe